# Search for drupal site using taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

We are due to move our website (a rather large charity site) and we would really like to make sure search is working as well as possible. We are currently working on tagging all our content using a controlled vocabulary taxonomy which we hope to be able to use in Drupal.

What I would like to know if there are any search modules for drupal, where search result would be displayed with visible taxonomy tags. So as for example if someone would search for "drugs" and "depression" a list of result would be displayed where you by the article also could see the taxonomy tags related to that article. So Search result one would have the tags "Drugs""Depression" and any other tags used so perhaps "stress", search result two "Drugs""Depression" and "Pain". I hope this makes sense? Does anybody know if this is possible and if so are there any website that uses something like this already?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear what you're asking, so I might be on the wrong track. However a basic search returns a set of nodes that match in a particular order; the normal culprits are Apache Solr and Elastic Search, but there are others. For a large site definitely don't use the builtin search, and do investigate using 'search api' if you're not already.

Once you have a set of nodes, it's up to you how to display them. Including the taxonomy terms associated with each node is part of the display logic, rather than the search itself, and should be relatively easy. Have a look at Display Suite for better control of search views if you need it, though it may well be more appropriate to write a custom node render hook.

If you are more interested in something like a tag cloud of terms that the currently matched nodes reference, that is more difficult but I would look at the tag cloud module, with some custom glue logic to link them.

Hope this helps...